# Simple Toggle(Jquery) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span tag; I want to have a toggle option for it. I tried to use JQuery, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
                <li class ="span2"><span id="test">Click here</span>
                    <ul class ="dropDown" id="idGraphic" style="display: none;">   
                        <li class ="span1" id ="photoAbout">
                            <?php
                                echo anchor(LINK_GRAPHIC_ABOUT, 'About', array('style' => 'color:white;'));
                            ?>
                        </li>
                        <li class ="span1" id ="photoGallery">
                            <?php                                
                                echo anchor(LINK_GRAPHIC_GALLERY, 'Gallery', array('class' => $hover, 'style' => 'color:white;'));                                                                                                
                            ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

and my Javascript code is:

```
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
  $( "#idGraphic" ).toggle();
});
```

So whenever I click on span with id=test It is supposed to show two ULs!

Please let me know if my code and my explanation is clear or not; if not please let me know which part you need more clarification.

Thanks

Comment: did you add the script in a dom ready handler

Comment: works here `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/5D2Cf/

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LBR2C/1/ ...

Comment: is there any error in the browser console ... also whether the elements are created dynamically

Comment: yes! but not working still...

Comment: If you have more than one, you need unique ids

Comment: are there multiple elements with id `test` of `idGraphic`?

Comment: Oh! the first time I go to Chrome bug (F12) it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) " for http://localhost/Project1/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.map but once I have my chrome bug (I dont know what you call it) and refresh it goes away! Is it a big deal?!

Comment: Yes. If there is a failing script, you do not know what else is blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code.  I suspect the PHP is generating blank data and you aren't seeing anything as a result of that

Comment: Just shows how giving the full story helps. Next time just view source first and paste the rendered HTML

Answer (score -1):

toggle has been deprecated.. you should check the visibility and set it to either show or hide..

```
if ($(this).is(':visible')) { $(this).hide() }
else { $(this).show()); }
```

Comment: Please show where toggle has been deprecated. The toggle(function,function) yes but not the hide/show version http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I guess instead of "this" you mean "#idGraphic"; but this one not working either!

Answer (score -1):

Original HTML:->

```
<li class ="span2">
  <span id="test">Click here</span>
    <ul class ="dropDown" id="idGraphic" style="display: none;">   
      <li class ="span1" id ="photoAbout">
        <?php
          echo anchor(LINK_GRAPHIC_ABOUT, 'About', array('style' => 'color:white;'));
        ?>
      </li>
      <li class ="span1" id ="photoGallery">
        <?php                                
          echo anchor(LINK_GRAPHIC_GALLERY, 'Gallery', array('class' => $hover, 'style' => 'color:white;'));                                                                                                
        ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Original Javascript:->

```
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
  $( "#idGraphic" ).toggle();
});
```

Edited Javascript:->

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').click(function() {
            $('#idGraphic').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Place the edited javascript code after the end of the closing body tag. I guess you have placed it in the head tag and that's the reason your jQuery code is getting executed before the page loads completely. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: No you do not place script after end body tag. With this amount of script you place it in the head and document.ready executes when the page has loaded